# Why would `docker images` and Docker Desktop on the same Ubuntu machine show lists of completely different images?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I had worked with Docker before on a Ubuntu machine and created some images. Then I installed Docker Desktop and created some more images. But now the command `docker images` and Docker Desktop seem to be completely out of sync showing different lists of images.

How can I get the docker CLI and Docker Desktop back in sync?

[image]

Comment: If you mean CMD as in the Windows command, this is not on Windows. It's on Ubuntu 22.04. In the screenshot above it shows the images that Docker Desktop knows of and the images that the command `docker images` shows in the terminal.

Comment: You seem to have two instances of Docker installed. One of them is Docker Desktop, the other, older one (to which the `docker` command connects) is something different. What is the output of `env | grep -i docker` ?

Comment: The output is empty. The word "docker" does not appear in the output of "env".

Comment: To make sure the `docker` command connects to the correct dockerd, open a new terminal window (this is important to rule out SSH), run `docker version`, and compare the output to what Docker Desktop displays. You may also want to add a screenshot of the latter, and copy-paste the former into the question.

Comment: Also stop Docker Desktop temporarily. (Don't just close the winfow, stop it explicitly.) Does `docker images` start returning an error? After starting Docker Desktop, does `docker images` start succeeding?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Docker under Windows (Docker desktop) and Docker under WSL (Ubuntu) which are two completely different docker instances, each one with its own private repository.

For that reason you see a different images list.

Comment: No, actually this machine is Ubuntu 22.04 on which I installed Docker Desktop, which has been available on Ubuntu since 2020 apparently. The Docker command line and Docker Desktop seem to be using different registries but I don't find anything official about this.

Comment: You can have the same issue if you install Docker Desktop on Linux; on all platforms Docker Desktop runs Docker in a Linux virtual machine.